# Error: No component factory found for ErrorComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, systemjs, snackbar

I am loading some components remotely using the following code abstract in the main app:

```
async loadRemoteModule() {
    const remoteModule = this.sysplexesService.getRemoteModule();

    // These library are already present, so no need to reload them.
    SystemJS.set('@angular/core', SystemJS.newModule(AngularCore));
    SystemJS.set('@angular/common', SystemJS.newModule(AngularCommon));
    SystemJS.set('@angular/material', SystemJS.newModule(AngularMaterial));
    SystemJS.set('@angular/material/snack-bar', SystemJS.newModule(AngularMaterialSnackbar));
    SystemJS.set('@angular/router', SystemJS.newModule(AngularRouter));
    SystemJS.set('d3', SystemJS.newModule(await import('d3')));
    SystemJS.set('@angular/common/http', SystemJS.newModule(HttpClientModule));
    SystemJS.set('moment', SystemJS.newModule(await import('moment')));
    SystemJS.set('@angular/flex-layout', SystemJS.newModule(FlexLayoutModule));
    SystemJS.set('@angular/platform-browser/animations', SystemJS.newModule(NoopAnimationsModule));
    SystemJS.set('@angular/forms', SystemJS.newModule(FormsModule));
    SystemJS.set('rxjs', SystemJS.newModule(rxjs));
    SystemJS.set('pi-common-lib', SystemJS.newModule(piCommonLib));
    SystemJS.set('@angular/animations', SystemJS.newModule(AngularAnimation));

    SystemJS.import(remoteModule.url).then((module) => {
      this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module[`${remoteModule.name}Module`])
        .then((moduleFactory) => {
          const moduleRef = moduleFactory.ngModuleFactory.create(this.injector);

          let factory = moduleFactory.componentFactories.find(
            item => item.componentType.name === `${remoteModule.name}Component`);

          if (factory) {
            const component = this.vc.createComponent(factory);
            const instance = component.instance;
          }
    });
  }
```

The following components are part of an Angular library that get loaded by the previous routine:

One of the library component uses an Angular material snackbar:
ssc.component.ts

```
notify(message: string, className: string) {
    this.snackBar.openFromComponent(ErrorComponent, {
      data: message, verticalPosition: 'top', panelClass: className,
      // data: message, verticalPosition: 'top', duration: 20000, 3: className,
    });
  }
```

and here is the custom snackbar ErrorComponent:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA, MatSnackBarRef } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

@Component({
    selector: 'izoa-error',
    templateUrl: './error.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./error.component.scss'],
    providers: [{ provide: MatSnackBarRef, useValue: {} }, {
        provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA, useValue: {}
    }]
})
export class ErrorComponent {

    constructor(public snackBarRef: MatSnackBarRef<ErrorComponent>, @Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any) { }
}
```

the module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  MatFormFieldModule, MatAutocompleteModule, MatBadgeModule, MatBottomSheetModule,
  MatButtonModule, MatButtonToggleModule, MatCardModule, MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule, MatDatepickerModule, MatDialogModule, MatDividerModule,
  MatExpansionModule, MatGridListModule, MatIconModule, MatInputModule,
  MatListModule, MatMenuModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatPaginatorModule,
  MatProgressBarModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatRadioModule, MatRippleModule,
  MatSelectModule, MatSidenavModule, MatSliderModule, MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatSortModule, MatStepperModule, MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule, MatToolbarModule, MatTooltipModule, MatTreeModule
} from '@angular/material';
import { MatSnackBarRef, MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from  '@angular/material/snack-bar';
...
import { ErrorComponent } from './ssc/error.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
...
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [ErrorComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: MatSnackBarRef, useValue: {} }, {
    provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA,
    useValue: {} // Add any data you wish to test if it is passed/used correctly
  }],
  imports: [
   ...
    MatSnackBarModule, ...
  ],
  exports: [
    Db2SscLibComponent
  ]
})
export class Db2SscLibModule { }
```

when the dynamic component loads, I get the following error:

```
core.js:15714 ERROR Error: No component factory found for ErrorComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:9875)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.js:9913)
    at CdkPortalOutlet.attachComponentPortal (portal.es5.js:654)
    at MatSnackBarContainer.attachComponentPortal (snack-bar.es5.js:392)
    at MatSnackBar._attach (snack-bar.es5.js:856)
    at MatSnackBar.openFromComponent (snack-bar.es5.js:695)
    at SscComponent.notify (ssc.component.ts:330)
    at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (ssc.component.ts:200)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:134)
```

the errorComponent is present as an entryComponent.

```
  entryComponents: [ErrorComponent],
```

If I use a basic snackbar instead, so errorComponent is not needed/loaded.

```
this.snackBar.open('We are sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact your administrator', 'Close', {
     duration: 20000,
       panelClass: className,
       verticalPosition: 'top',
       data: message
     });
```

the module is loaded dynamically and the snackbar displays successfully.

If I run the library standalone, it works fine with the openFromComponent

```
this.snackBar.openFromComponent(ErrorComponent, {
      data: message, verticalPosition: 'top', panelClass: className,
      // data: message, verticalPosition: 'top', duration: 20000, 3: className,
    });
```

It's only when I try to load it dynamically using compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync that I get the previous error.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also validated that the ErrorComponent factory is present in 'moduleFactory.componentFactories'.  
The issue seems to originate from the Angular Material snackbar not being able to inject the factory properly:
this.snackBar.openFromComponent(ErrorComponent,